# array of object type in typescript with angular2

Tags: arrays, typescript

in my angular application I want to use an array of object of id and role in below manner

```
let userRole: Array<...> = [
                       { id: 1, name: 'Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Super Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'User' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Watcher' }
                    ];
```

BUT I am confused what need to fill up in place of ***...*** ?

`Array < Object >` or `Array <Any>`

**Trial 1 :**

`var role = {
            id: number;
            name: string;
        };`

and then `Array <role>` but it gives error

**Trial 2 :**  adding with different class file

#### role.ts

```
export class Role {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string
    ) { }
}
```

and add in my file as

```
import { Role }      from './role';

export class HeroFormComponent {

   let userRole: Array<Role> = [
                       { id: 1, name: 'Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Super Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'User' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Wacher' }
                    ];
```

But gives error

**Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first and best option is to simply not have a type annotation:

```
let userRole = [
                       { id: 1, name: 'Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Super Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'User' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Watcher' }
                    ];
```

The inferred type of `userRole` will be `Array<{ id: number, name: string }>`.

If you really want a type annotation for whatever reason, you can write either

```
let userRole: { id: number, name: string }[] = [ ...
```

or

```
let userRole: Array<{ id: number, name: string }> = [ ...
```

These two syntaxes are identical in behavior.

If you're going to be using this type a lot, you might want to make an interface for it so you can re-use the name in other places:

```
interface Role {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Now you can write

```
let userRole: Role[] = [ ...
```

When you declare an initialized field in a class, you do not use `var` or `let`:

```
export class HeroFormComponent {

   userRole = [
                       { id: 1, name: 'Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Super Admin' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'User' },
                       { id: 2, name: 'Wacher' }
                    ];
```

Again here, you can pick and choose which type annotation you'd like to have.

Comment: and where do I write this interface code? inside angular class ? or outside class? and if i write outside the class then do i need to extend this interface?

Comment: Answers, respectively: Wherever it belongs (probably at top-level in a file), no, no, and no